# How to get first row of has_and_belongs_to_many relationship postgres sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

The relationship between the model 'battle' to the model 'category' is has_and_belongs_to_many. I'm trying to find all the battles that don't relate to a specific category.
What I tried to do so far is:

```
Battle.all.includes(:categories).where("(categories[0].name NOT IN ('Other', 'Fashion'))")
```

This error occurred: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  cannot subscript type categories because it is not an array`

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: You should do .where("(categories.name NOT IN ('Other', 'Fashion'))")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `categories[0].name` is not a valid SQL reference to the `name` column of categories.

Try this:

```
Battle.includes(:categories).reject do |battle| 
  ['Other', 'Fashion'].include? battle.categories.map(&:name)
end
```

Note that this code performs two queries - one for `Battle` and one for `Category` - and eager loads the appropriate `Category` Active Record objects into the instantiated `Battle` records' `:categories` relationship. This is helpful to prevent N+1 queries as described [in details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) in the guides.

Also note that the code above first loads to memory ALL `Battle` records before eliminating the ones that have the undesired categories. Depending on your data, this could be prohibitive. If you prefer to restrict the SQL query so that only the relevant ActiveRecord objects get instantiated, you could get away with something like the following:

```
battle_ids_sql = Battle.select(:id).joins(:categories).where(categories: {name: ['Other' ,'Fashion']}).to_sql
Battle.where("id NOT IN (#{battle_ids_sql})")
```

`battle_ids_sql` is an SQL statement that returns battle IDs that HAVE one of your undesired categories. The SQL which is actually executed fetches all `Battle` records that are not in that inner SQL. It's effective, although use sparingly - queries like this tend to become hard to maintain rather quickly.

You can learn about `joins`, `includes` and two other related methods (`eager_load` and `preload`) [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

Comment: I think this will not give the desired result set - it will return all Battles that are in a category other than 'Other' or 'Fashion'. It if a Battle is in Category 'X' and category 'Fashion', it will be returned. If a Battle is not in any category, it will not be returned.

Comment: You're very right. Thanks for catching it. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Excellent - good job with describing the limitations inherent in the first method (using 'reject') Interesting problem - the statement of the problem is simple, but no so with the solution!